# Xamarins Forms UWP App Images on scaled display

Tags: xamarin.forms, image-scaling, xamarin.uwp

I have a laptop with a 4k display.  The display properties are set to 3840 X 2160 (Recommended) for the resolution and the scale factor is set to 250% again, the recommended value.  I have images in my project scaled with the following suffixes:

.scale-100.png
.scale-150.png
.scale-200.png
.scale-250.png
.scale-300.png
.scale-350.png
.scale-400.png

based on the documentation I found.

When I run the app, the images show up huge and throw the rest of the display off.  Below is a screen shot:

[image]

if I set the scale to 100% - everything is tiny, but the images are correct.  Here is a screen shot.

[image]

any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Did you try to set the size on platform specific ?

Comment: @FabriBertani, I am not quite sure what you mean.  I will say that I simply removed all the scale-XXX images, put a base 32X32 image in the root and updated the app to use that and it looks fine to me.  I was just trying to get the newer approach to image scaling in UWP apps to work.

Answer (score 0):

Derive from official document.

> UWP image file names can be [suffixed with .scale-xxx before the file extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-resources/images-tailored-for-scale-theme-contrast), where xxx is the percentage of scaling applied to the asset, e.g. myimage.scale-200.png. Images can then be referred to in code or XAML without the scale modifier, e.g. just myimage.png. The platform will select the nearest appropriate asset scale based on the display's current DPI.

From your screen, it looks get the correct scale image, but your image control has been scale, Please try to set `Aspect` property as Fill for image control.

> set the size on platform specific

[`OnPlatform`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/device) is used to set specific value for each platform. For example

```
<StackLayout>
  <StackLayout.Margin>
    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness">
      <On Platform="iOS" Value="0,20,0,0" />
      <On Platform="Android, UWP" Value="0,0,0,0" />
    </OnPlatform>
  </StackLayout.Margin>
  ...
</StackLayout>
```

You could specific `StackLayout` margin for each platform like code above.

Comment: as you can see from the question I posted, I already have the images with the .scale-xxx. suffix.  The image being displayed still is too large.    Also I am familiar with the OnPlatform but how exactly would I use that to solve this problem as it appears to be related to the scaling of the display on a windows machine and not the actual platform.

Comment: Is there by chance an easy way to tell which image (I.e. which suffix) is being used in the running app?  This may tell me if I simply need to rescale my images but I am not sure that is actually the case.  It would also let me know if when running on an unscaled display the app is picking a different file than when the display is scaled.

Comment: You could try to use Converter to detect the image suffix. For more please refer this [document ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/converters).

Comment: - OK I will try that.  Thank you